# getting null when using Where clause in python sql

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a table userToken with three columns:

```
piEmail , piCode, piToken
```

This is how I created this table:

```
class UserToken(models.Model):
    piEmail                    = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    piCode                     = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    piToken                    = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True, default=uuid4)
```

piToken is autoFill, I do not insert this value.

Now I am inserting value in this table and in the next line trying to fetch the token value for the random value which I inserted in table:

```
 random_number = User.objects.make_random_password(length=10, allowed_chars='123456789abcdefghijklmno')
 userToken_instance = UserToken.objects.create(piEmail='abc@abc.com', piCode=random_number)
 userToken_instance.save()

 cursor = connection.cursor()
 cursor.execute("SELECT piToken FROM app_usertoken where piCode = %s", (random_number,))
 row = cursor.fetchall()
```

But it is returning null , when I check in the table, value is there.

Comment: did you call `userToken_instance.save()` before checking the db?

Comment: Yes, I am. Updated the code but same issue.

Comment: issue is this query is giving error only when I use where clause , if i run simply select piToken from app_usertoken  then it returns record. I cant believe there is not a single perfect solution available for this